# Make a simple SQL query faster

Tags: mysql, sql

I found that the same query gets logged in my slow-log again and again, but I don't really know how to make it any faster. I believe I did most of the optimization possible. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT merk_id FROM profile_merk WHERE profile_id = '51485e0d9ce6d'
```

The profile_id varies with every query of course. The table has about 40 mln rows and 2 columns. One column is merk_id and the other is profile_id. I have the following indexes on the table:

```
Tbl | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation| Cardinality | Sub_part    
profile_merk |  0 | PRIMARY |   1 | merk_id |   A | 4125 |  NULL |  NULL |      BTREE       
profile_merk |  0 | PRIMARY |   2 |     profile_id |    A |     39101247 |  NULL |  NULL |      BTREE       
profile_merk |  1 | profile_id |    1 |     profile_id |    A|  131212 |    NULL |  NULL |      BTREE       
profile_merk |  1 | merk_id |   1 |     merk_id |   A |     4125 |  NULL |  NULL |      BTREE
```

And the explain statement of the query gives the following:

```
id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra    
1 | SIMPLE | profile_merk | ref | profile_id | profile_id | 62 | const | 1688 | Using where
```

What more can I do to optimize the performance? I realise it's kind of an open question, but any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please make it a practice to format your code to a readable way. You have posted a table, of which the columns are not aligned properly. You have also used tabs, which mess up the formatting of the SO's markdown editor. Please don't just copy paste. Check in the preview how it looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this simple query:

```
SELECT merk_id
FROM profile_merk
WHERE profile_id = '51485e0d9ce6d';
```

The best performance is using a composite key:

```
create index idx_profilemark_profileid_merkid on profile_mark(profile_id, merk_id)
```

The problem with the primary key is that the two columns are not in the order needed for this query.  There is a big difference between an index on `profile_mark(profile_id, merk_id)` and `profile_mark(merk_id, profile_id)`.  In essence, the index will be used from the left to the right with `where` clause getting the first chance to use index columns.

Comment: Probably it make sense to advice OP to reduce the `profile_id` column length since 62 looks like an overkill for the given data

Comment: It might be a little faster, but only because all the data you return (merk_id) is in the index as well, so no data needs to be read for the table. But to me this feels like abusing the index, since the index isn't really used for joining and filtering. As soon as you need a different field as well, performance will be slower again, unless you are going to add that field to the index too, but that doesn't sound like a proper solution. So yes, it might work, but it's not really future proof.

Comment: +1 Very cool. One question, can you please include a link to the mysql implementation / theory that describes this?

Comment: @maythesource.com: ["mysql covering index" in google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql%20covering%20index)

Comment: @zerkms That's not exactly a direct reference for this specific case. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html may be a better one.

Comment: @GolezTrol: there are only 2 columns in the table ;-)

Comment: @maythesource.com: "covering index" is the exact term for the solution explained in the question. It is relevant, but I cannot agree that your link to documentation explains anything about covering indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Index is applied, now I will just have to wait and see what the performance result is. @zerkms: 62 isn't the column lenght if I'm not mistaken, it the number of bytes of the key used. The column lenght is 20, but that's not something you could have extracted from the given info.